# How do I get dependent views to update automatically in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

Somebody at our firm decided to use 3 views to support a webpage, and they have to contain a subset of columns that are identical. So I have definitions like this:

```
CREATE VIEW EmailReceivedView
AS
SELECT     
    dbo.EmailReceived.ID
    , ...lots of columns
FROM  dbo.EmailReceived 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ...more tables

--Emails related to reviews
CREATE VIEW ReviewEmailReceivedView
AS
SELECT RV.ReviewID, V.*
FROM ReviewEmailReceived RV
INNER JOIN EmailReceivedView V ON EmailReceivedID = V.ID

--Emails related to grants
CREATE VIEW GrantEmailReceivedView
AS
SELECT GV.GrantID, V.*
FROM GrantEmailReceived GV 
INNER JOIN EmailReceivedView V ON GV.EmailReceivedID = V.ID
```

Now the reason I did V.* in the dependent views is that in the event that the supporting view changes, I want the the dependent views to reflect the changes. But that doesn't happen in SQL Server unless I rerun the scripts as ALTER scripts. Why not? And is there a way to ensure that changes to a supporting view are automatically reflected in the dependencies?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is also [`sp_refreshsqlmodule`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326754.aspx) which I prefer only because you can also use it for modules that aren't views. To build a script that refreshes all views, though, you could do this:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @sql = N'';

SELECT @sql = @sql + N'
  EXEC sys.sp_refreshsqlmodule 'N'' 
  + QUOTENAME(s.name) + N'.'
  + QUOTENAME(v.name) + N''';'
FROM sys.views AS v
INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s
ON v.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
WHERE v.is_ms_shipped = 0
-- AND v.name LIKE '%EmailReceivedView%'
;

PRINT @sql;
-- EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;
```

But more to the point, this is *exactly* why [you shouldn't use `SELECT *` in a view](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list).

Comment: Agreed, and accepted as the answer. Not an appropriate use of SELECT *. I suspect that WITH SCHEMABINDING is what is required to ensure the views remain consistent.

Comment: Agreed, especially the part about "this is exactly why you shouldn't use SELECT * in a view."

Comment: @Colin, did you use `with schemabinding`? Did it help you in updating views automatically?

Answer (score 2):

[sp_refreshview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187821.aspx):

```
sp_refreshview [ @viewname = ] 'viewname'
```

[SQL Server – refresh all Views](http://www.sqlserver-dba.com/2011/01/sql-server-refresh-all-views.html)

Comment: What if there are dependencies between these views, for example one view A depends on view B, however the sp_refreshview runs first on A and then on B, meaning that A will not contain the latest B changes?