# To add a column to a view

Tags: sql-server, sql-view

I am now working on a View in SQL Server 2012 which is very long (has around 800 columns). We allow users to add custom columns to the table(A separate UI that allows user to specify column name, type and max length).Once the column is added to the table, it must be reflected in the view too. Is there a way to automatically accomplish this ? Right now, I need to create an alter view statement with the already existing 800+ columns and newly added column. Also, can sp_refreshview be used for this purpose? Looking for some answers. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have a view with 800 columns in it, you already have something evil!

Comment: hmmm...i agree. but it has been like that . I cannot change that now..Please let me know if there is any other way to achieve this.

Comment: Do you really need a view? Otherwise you could just construct a SELECT command in the application (front-end) and execute it directly.

Comment: If you google sp_refreshview you'll find it is ideal for what you need. I would add call to it to the UI through which users add their own columns. So after new column is added view is refreshed..

Comment: Nope...That view has a lot of dependencies on many projects. This is a small functionality that i am required to add for the user. There is no way at present to remove the view.

Comment: You could look into `DDL Triggers`.

Answer (score 0):

If you manually set which columns are included to view (I mean `SELECT column1, column2 FROM`), then the automatic update probably isn't possible.
If `SELECT *` is used in view (bad practice), there is a [solution](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1427/table-changes-not-automatically-reflected-in-a-sql-server-view/):

```
exec sp_refreshview [dbo.v_customer]
```

And its more common form [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12496465/how-do-i-get-dependent-views-to-update-automatically-in-sql-server) (update all views).

Comment: Thanks IIya.. The view is created with joins from many tables . So i understand sp_refreshview or sp_refreshsql is not going to help.